# Excel Countif - Need no. of cells in a row that have a date greater than specific date

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, excel-2007, countif

I have a table like this, where I want to insert formulas in column B to arrive at the indicated values.

The logic is this - I want to count every alternate cell in that particular row, starting from column C till column AA, and get the number of cells that contain a date value greater than or equal to Target date.

```
Cols/Rows      A        B     C      D     E         F      G
  1       Target Date   X   X Date   Y    Y Date     Z    Z Date
  2       13-12-2015    2               13-12-2015       13-01-2016
  3       24-11-2015    1               25-11-2015       20-10-2015
  4       23-01-2016    0                   
  5       30-01-2016    0               06-06-2016       14-04-2015
```

To begin with, before I put the condition on the date, I first tried to get the number of alternate columns in this range by using the array formula `=IF(MOD(COLUMN($C4:$AA4),2)=0,COLUMNS($C4:$AA4))`

But this returns `FALSE` for some reason. Only if this returns a numeric value, I can proceed with adding a condition for dates.

How do I modify the formula? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN($C4:$AA4),2)=0)*($C4:$AA4>=DATEVALUE"13/1/2015")*($C4:$AA4<=DATEVALUE"13/1/2016"))
```

This will return a count of every other column that has a date between 13/1/2015 and 13/1/2016

Comment: Thank you! Supposing I want to have the range as $A4:$AA4, is there any way by which I can exclude only the current cell in which I type the formula, so as to avoid circular reference?

Comment: @user3164272 not that I know, You could just add a second sumproduct to the first to get the cells on the left and right.

Comment: Thanks, that kind of helps. I shall give it a shot.

Comment: In some cells though, I have text values such as "Due". Those are also getting counted as greater than the specified date. For example, in cell E4, if I type some text, then B4 gives the value as 1 instead of 0. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to Excel at the moment to check, but I suspect the issue is that you're calling `COLUMN` with arguments. I think if you remove the range, and do `=IF(MOD(COLUMN(), 2)=0, COLUMNS($C4:$AA4)` the if will at least get true on even columns. `COLUMN` returns the numeric index of the current column, so you might need to fiddle with things to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

The brute-force approach, write as many of these as you need,
    =1*(C5>A5) + 1*(E5>A5) + 1*(G5>A5) + 1*(I5>A5)
and so on.

Comment: Brute Force would not help me here, since I need to modify the formula each time a new column with data is added.